# ggplot line cutts-off when i add color

Tags: r, dataframe

I made a line plot with ggplot and it worked, but when I added colors (group by a categorical column) to the plot, a part of the line graph cut off, How do I make this line stay with colors.
Below is my code and result before and after I added colors.

Code without color

```
ggplot(Data,aes(x=date, y=controlV,))+
  geom_line()+
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b %Y"))
```

Result
[image: ggplot without color]

Code without color

```
ggplot(Data,aes(x=date`, y=controlv, group = Controlling_V))+ geom_line(aes(color= Controlling_V))+ scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b %Y")+ scale_color_manual(values=c('darkblue','Red'))
```

Result
[image: ggplot with color]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by default geom_line splits the data into groups using the colour. You can override this by explicitly specifying groups, e.g.

```
data <- data.frame(x=1:100, 
                   y=c(runif(30), 0.6+runif(70)), 
                   g=c(group=rep(1,30), rep(2,70)))
ggplot(data, aes(x=x, y=y, color=g)) + geom_line(group=1)
```

producing output where the different colours join together:

[image: Output plot]

Comment: At the moment we can't replicate your problem because you haven't given us example data.